# AuthenticationMethod claim missing after two-factor authentication

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with AspNetCore 2 Identity and have setup a user with two-factor authentication using an authenticator app.  The authentication all works and I can see an **amr** claim with value **pwd**, however I would also have expected (or was hoping) to see another **amr** claim with value **mfa** to indicate the user logged in using a two-factor mechanism.

I created my own SignInManager and provided an override to SignInAsync and I can see the principal does not have any amr claims so I think the existing amr claim is being added by the cookie/authentication middleware (or IS4 perhaps?).

Some questions:

1. What should I do to obtain an amr claim with a value "mfa" when using the mfa workflow?
2. Should AspNetCore Identity take responsibility for setting amr and idp claims rather than relying on the underlying middleware?
3. Lastly, which middleware is actually setting the amr claim when one is not provided by aspnet Identity?

Answer (score 1):

1. What should I do to obtain an amr claim with a value "mfa" when using the mfa workflow?

You need to add user claim when users are signing in, I was also expecting from them to provide a way which tells whether any user is logged in with MFA or not.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/10636/files/20e985764097b60ebfae48bdb9f4005558b73e29#diff-9a3a4da09ce42b77457c5f3f23ced7fa

.NET Core 3.0 preview recently included a method to find out the same.

```
   List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim("amr", "mfa"),
    };

    identityResult = await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);
```

You can probably add this code when signing in and then clearing this claim when logging out, but there will be many issues tackling this problem, unless they provide some methods.